# Is it possible to run a .NET core 3.1 app on Windows 7 Embedded?

Tags: wpf, .net-core, windows-7-embedded

I am trying to run a .NET Core 3.1 WPF application on a Windows 7 Embedded VM. Unfortunately, Windows 7 Embedded does not officially support .NET Core. Is there a workaround to get this to work anyway?

I have already tried publishing the app as a self-contained package, and as a single file (which is also self-contained), hoping that this would include all the necessary dependencies. But unfortunately, this didn't work. The event viewer showed me this exception:

```
Message: Failed to load the dll from (path)\hostfxr.dll, HRESULT:0x80070057
The library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from (path)\hostfxr.dll failed
- Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
  (download link)
```

But of course that installer does not work on Windows 7 embedded ("This update is not applicable to your computer").

Is there a way to manually include all necessary dependencies, to get this to load anyway?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.0/3.0-supported-os.md - Upgrade the OS version?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible. There is other software running on that machine that cannot run on later OS versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error regarding hostfxr.dll while starting from a barebones Windows 7 installation.  Microsoft lists a specific security patch that fixed the error once I installed it.

**KB3063858**

64-bit: https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=47442
32-bit: https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=47409

**.Net 5/Core Dependencies**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net50#dependencies

[.Net 5/Core Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5sNQ.png)